# How can one control the size of serialized object of Json serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, flexjson

Lets assume following is my object model:

```
Person {
String name;
List<Address> addressesList;
}

Address 
{
String field1;
String field2;
}
```

I am trying to serialize the Person object using flex JSon Serializer. I have some limit on the size of the serialized object, which can't be exceeded. What I want to do is truncate the addressesList (serilaize the less number  of addresses), so that limit isn't exceeded. I am wondering if there is way aforementioned use case can be be implemented ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- you can do this by adding your addresses one at a time and checking to see whether you have exceeded your limit. (Save each "still good" string and revert if needed).  Creating the full JSON text and removing addresses one by one from the last address is another alternative ... but the  logic might be more difficult.

If you hit the size limitation rarely, you could use the following strategy:

- Serialize the Person object
- if within limits return
- Otherwise recreate the person object with one less address, reserialize and check
- repeat as neccessary.

Comment: I am passing the Person object for serialization, how can I add addresses one at a time for serialization ? OR you are suggesting i add addresses to Person object one at a time, won't that be very inefficient way to do it ?

Comment: I was thinking on the same lines, but I was wondering if there is more efficient way to do it.